# JS Find and Replace mulitple words at once

Tags: javascript, replace

I am modifying [this](http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/03/07/how-to-find-and-replace-text-dynamically-via-javascript/) find/replace JS to be able to replace two words at the same time.

My code works except only with the last word I use as show [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WLZjV/)

Answer (score 1):

Calling string.replace returns the new string with the replaced text, without modifying the original string itself.

So your code:

```
replaced = haystackText.replace(...)
```

is setting the updated text into the variable "replaced", but never updating the variable "haystackText".

Additionally, since you do this:

```
if (haystackText.length == 0) {
      haystackText = document.getElementById("haystack").innerHTML;
 }
```

It will only set the haystackText the first time the method is called, but not the second. It doesn't look like you have a need for leaving haystackText as a global variable (outside of the method), so changing this:

```
 if (haystackText.length == 0) {
      haystackText = document.getElementById("haystack").innerHTML;
 }
```

to this:

```
var haystackText = document.getElementById("haystack").innerHTML;
```

would fix your problem.

Comment: It sure does! Thanks so much!